# Completely wiping dotnetnuke cache

Tags: c#, caching, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Have created a module in DotNetNuke 7. Have made changes on my local test version which has created several rows in the database. I then copied these rows into the live database but they dont appear in the live version of the module. Have tried clearing the cache through host settings and restarting the application and it still won't show new rows. Have even tried setting cache settings to non-specified and still won't load new rows. Is there a way I can completely reset and get it find the new rows. This is an extremely irritating feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used the "Tools, Clear Cache and Reset Application" option, you likely are running into some other issue, not caching related. Or a Browser Cache issue perhaps.

I would start by confirming that the data is actually there (always best to just double check, even if you think it is).

Make sure your module is connecting to the proper table (maybe you're using a objectQualifier in development but not in production)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the application should kill the cache, BUT, make sure that you don't have EnableCachePersistence set to True in the appSettings section of your web.config.

Otherwise, all of Chris Hammond's recommendations are the best next steps.